# sql server xml querying?

Tags: xml, sql-server-2005

If I have the XML like the following: (As an XML variable names @nodes)

```
<Nodes>
    <Item>Item 1</Item>
    <Item>Item 2</Item>
    <Item>Item 3</Item>
</Nodes>
```

And I also have the index of the item I am looking for (example 2). How can I get the value 'Item 2' using a query?

I have been trying something like this:

```
  SELECT
@result = @nodes.value('(/Nodes/Item)[2]', 'nvarchar(255)')
```

But all I can seem to get back is NULL

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your approach works for me.

Here's how I assigned the XML to the variable.

```
declare @nodes as xml 
set @nodes = '<Nodes>
    <Item>Value 5</Item>
    <Item>Localhost</Item>
    <Item>Unrouteable - 10.x.x.x</Item>
    <Item>Unrouteable - 172.16-31.x.x</Item><Item>Unrouteable - 192.168.x.x</Item>
</Nodes>'

SELECT
@nodes.value('(/Nodes/Item)[2]', 'nvarchar(255)')
```

Comment: Ah damn.. I changed a couple things when I was pasting my example.. guess I must have fixed it then. Thanks!